# Subtracting and changing datetime in Teradata

Tags: datetime, format, teradata, subtraction

My `Col_1` looks like this-

> 1/20/2015 11:12:00.000000
>
> 1/21/2015 13:00:00.000000

... and so on.

I want to do (row 2 -row 1) and display the result as 1572 minutes.

Also, can someone tell me how to simply change the format of this cell to
`mm/dd/yy hh:mm:ss`

and get rid of all the decimals?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you thinking in the right direction. The `ORDER BY` of the window function may need to be another column on your table if you don't want the window ordered by the actual column you are trying to do the time arithmetic. If you can share more details about the table or take a stab at the SQL yourself, we might be able to arrive at a better solution.

```
SELECT (MIN(Col_1)
            OVER(PARTITION BY 1 ORDER BY Col_1
            ROWS BETWEEN 1 FOLLOWING AND 1 FOLLOWING) -
       Col_1) MINUTE(4) AS MinutesElapsed
  FROM MyTable;
```

Using the raw data you have given as a sample:

```
SELECT (TIMESTAMP '2015-01-21 13:00:00.00000' -
        TIMESTAMP '2015-01-20 11:12:00.00000') MINUTE(4) AS MinutesElapsed;
```

As for the decimals:

```
SELECT CAST(Col_1 AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AS NewTimeStamp;
```

Comment: The last code did not help. It gave me a datetime field overflow.

Comment: Could you tell me a code that gets rid of the decimals. Your code did not help. Gave me a datetime field overflow.

Comment: Can you post your SQL and sample data?